# How do I completly remove Openjdk from redhat

Tags: java

I am using `Redhat 6`, I was working with `java 1.6` because I had a requirement to work with `java 1.6`. I update my redhat using 
`yum uppdate` and `openjdk 1.8` got automatically installed.
I tried to remove openjdk using

```
yum remove java*
```

`java 1.6` got remove but not openjdk.

and then I tried `yum remove openjdk*` this dint work.
 I tried to remove from UI but from there I am able to list openjdk 1.8 but not getting the option to remove it.
How do I completely remove `openjdk`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

First Find java product and version using below command:

```
rpm -qa | grep java
```

And

```
rpm -qa | grep jdk
```

**OUTPUT** like:

```
jdk1.7.0
```

Then remove package using *RPM* or *YUM*:

```
yum remove jdk1.7.0
```

or

`rpm -e jdk1.7.0`

Comment: I'm trying to do this on Fedora 25. But instead of removing just the OpenJDK java installation it appears that it wants to remove all java packages that are dependent on this? Every time it asks me to remove 75+ other packages. It's not good, because I want to install Oracle Java instead and don't want to re-install all the other packages..?

Comment: It is always recommend using yum vs. rpm, because rpm commands can rip things out of the rpm database without caring about dependencies. yum will print warnings and show everything it is removing

Answer (score 12):

```
rpm -qa | grep openjdk | xargs  yum -y remove
```